# Is it grammatically okay to say " in a similar way as (subject + verb)"?

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically okay to say " in a similar way as (subject + verb)"?
For example, "A behaves in a similar way as B does".

Or should I choose another expression for this meaning to be grammatically better?

Comment: "*... in a similar way **to** B*"

Comment: *"...behaves **similarly to** B"*

Comment: You may have chosen a poor example, because it's so easy to eliminate the word "does" from a sentence. Suppose we want to say that the way Berta writes software is similar (somehow) to the way Jake bakes a cake; you might want to write, "Berta codes in a similar way as Jake bakes." I think you'd want to rewrite that sentence, though.

Answer (score 1):

We Americans always say "similar to" as if similarity draws two things closer TO one another, but "different from" as if difference separates two things FROM one another.   There are variations among American, British, Canadian and Australian English on this point.  I know that some non-US English speakers (Australians, for sure) say "different to"; whereas US speakers would not say "different to"; only "different from" or "different than"(except to say "It sure sounds different to me when you talk like that!")

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out in a comment, we say "**similar to**" [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/similar).

> - He behaves in a similar way to me.
> - He behaves pretty much the way I do.
> - He behaves very much as I do.
> - His behavior is similar to mine.

Comment: And if you wish to retain a full sentence after _in a similar way to_, you need to make it a subordinate clause headed by _how_: “He eats his hot dogs in a similar way to how a snake eats a crocodile”.

Answer (score -1):

your sentence is acceptable but you should change it into:
**1.A behaves a similar way to B
2.A behaves in a similar way that B does
3.A behaves in a similar way,as well as B does**There is many way to use,i don't know if it's any grammatical issue in this sentence but its structure is ok.

Comment: Examples 2 and 3 sound wrong to me.

Comment: it doesn't mean that it is wrong

Comment: Let me put it this way: I do not recall ever seeing either of those constructions in literate writing and I would recommend not to use them.